# PHP / MySQL select by DATETIME field across DST change

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

Please forgive me if this unclear, but I am having a tough time trying to get what is in my mind down on paper.

#### Scenario:

We store a variety of jobs in a table. These are all timestamped using DATETIME set to UTC time zone.

Our users may have their timezones set in their preferences, so that we can transcribe system times to the users local times.

Now, assume that a user goes to select all jobs that were entered on October 25, 2012 (local user time):

```
+--------------------------------------+------------+---------+---------------------+
| id                                   | project_id | amount  | created             |
+--------------------------------------+------------+---------+---------------------+
| 50889ba5-77b4-41e1-a942-1dea0ab761f6 |   15076850 |   50.00 | 2012-10-25 01:53:41 |
| 5088b9a3-8110-446e-81c8-75da341f3f95 |   15076850 | 2000.00 | 2012-10-25 04:01:39 |
| 5088c852-d434-41e6-ba5d-27560ab761f6 |   15076850 |  100.00 | 2012-10-25 05:04:18 |
| 50892a3b-ad9c-4a32-aebf-384c0ab761f6 |   15076850 |  500.00 | 2012-10-25 12:02:03 |
| 50893098-6b9c-4028-9a87-3eb20ab761f6 |   15076850 |   25.00 | 2012-10-25 12:29:12 |
| 50894b10-d260-4f61-8eb9-1d190ab761f6 |   15076850 |   25.00 | 2012-10-25 14:22:08 |
| 50895129-48c8-4bb4-928f-483b341f3f95 |   15076850 |   25.00 | 2012-10-25 14:48:09 |
| 50896019-7144-4e74-8037-4160341f3f95 |   15076850 |   50.00 | 2012-10-25 15:51:53 |
+--------------------------------------+------------+---------+---------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If this user is in the Eastern United States (EST), and the times in this table are UTC, the results are going to come across as October 24th for the first two rows in the table results. Basically, I want to exclude those first two rows if the user is EST.

I have been experimenting with the use of `DateTime()`, however - I am stuck because this spans DST end (November 4, 2012). When I select the date on October 25th, DST is active, so it shows the users local time as UTC -0400. When the job ends, it is after (UTC -0500).

I am completely stuck on how to make this work.

Comment: Well, mysql will always use the server time, so, if you want to use the clients time, find out what timezone he is in and add/substract the hours from your time, when executing the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the UTC timestamp for what is the user's midnight (which is 4am UTC in the below example):

```
$start = new DateTime('2012-10-25 00:00:00', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$start->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$start = $start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// do the same with $end

SELECT ... WHERE `created` BETWEEN $start AND $end
```

The final query should select `WHERE BETWEEN 2012-10-25 04:00:00 AND 2012-10-26 03:59:59`, which is the day of October 25th in America/New York.

This should also work during DST changes. On November 4th, the query would be `BETWEEN 2012-11-04 04:00:00 AND 2012-11-05 04:59:59`, encompassing one more hour.

Comment: That seems to work - however, assuming I have '2012-10-25' as my DATE stamp, how can i get 2012-10-26 03:59:59 from that?

Comment: You make a `DateTime` instance for `2012-10-25 23:59:59` and change its timezone.